# Help with data manipulation

Tags: data

I'm fairly new to Mathematica and I'm trying to manipulate some data but its not going very well. I want to import a text file into Mathematica(its a list of chapter headings and page numbers of a book) and be able to print out the page number when i/user type(s) in the chapter heading. How do i go about it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details about your list. Preferably provide a small sample of, say, 10 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Let `list` be your list of chapter headings and page no

```
 list = {{"my first heading", 2}, {"My 2 heading",7}, {"Heading no. 3", 11}};
```

You can use the function given below
which takes in the chapter heading as its argument and spits out the corresponding page number as listed in `list`

```
 f[chapterHeading_] := 
  DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
    If[Sort[Characters[
    StringReplace[StringTrim[ToString[chapterHeading]], 
     Whitespace -> ""]]] === 
   Sort[Characters[
    StringReplace[StringTrim[list[[i, 1]]], Whitespace -> ""]]], 
  Sow[list[[i, 2]]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]], Null]
```

Now we test the function by evaluating `f[my first heading]` which gives `{2}`.
The chapter headings are case sensitive but you can type without spaces which means `f[myfirstheading]` also gives `{2}`